# Showing Unique keys?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I don't know if here is the right place to ask this question. Anyway, what I want to do is to show [Unique keys](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.8.1/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:PersistEntity). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Unique record` value you can use `getBy` to get `Entity record` and show its key.

```
do
  r <- getBy u
  let s = show $ entityKey r
```

Comment: I know we can show the `key`... I mean I want to show `Unique` itself.

Comment: `Unique rec` is just a data type that wraps some fields of `rec`. Why do you want to show it if you can show `rec`?

Comment: Two reasons. 1) After modifying `Unique record` several times, I can't be bothered to unwrap `Unique record`s and show `record`s  each time. 2) If there's no trouble, I think there's no reason not to make `Unique record` showable.

Comment: I'd like to show it like this:

`mapM_ print persistUniqueKeys (Foo "foo")`